# vba copy and paste one cell vs another

Tags: excel, vba

I am an extreme novice to VBA and have only found myself getting into it because as I research it seems to be the only way to accomplish what I want within excel.

In this case I have a button that should either copy data from specified cells in G or K to a different location of specified cells within the same worksheet.

The first part that copies data from either G16:G18 or K16:K18 works seamlessly. I wonder if it is because there are no formulas in these cells, just numbers.

The next part of the code however seems to only copy from K21 or K19 and I am unsure why this keeps happening. I have formulas in these cells and I believe because of the order I have it is just copying the results from the last active range even if that result is “”.

Below is the code I have now:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
        ActiveSheet.Range("G16:G18").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("P38:P40").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

        ActiveSheet.Range("K16:K18").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("P38:P40").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

        ActiveSheet.Range("G21").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("K39").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

        ActiveSheet.Range("G17").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("K40").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

        ActiveSheet.Range("K21").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("K39").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

        ActiveSheet.Range("K19").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("K40").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Is it because of the pastevalues? 
Is there a way around this?

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you step through the code, what happens after the `ActiveSheet.Range("P38:P40").PasteSpecial ...`? Does it go to the next `.Copy` line? (Also, you're just overwriting values in that second part, rendering `...(G16:G18).copy` pointless.  Finally, instead of `.Copy / .Paste`, you can just set the ranges' values equal to eachother if you just want the data. For example, the first two lines can be rewritten `Range("P38:P40").Value = Range("G16:G18").Value`

Comment: Add this to a `With ActiveSheet` block for much better readability

Comment: Hi @BruceWayne- yes it does just go to the next copy line. There should only be data entered in either cells G16:G18 OR cells K16:K18 based on rate type (daily or package charge) not both.

Comment: @BruceWayne - the problem seems to be with the cells that I have formulas in to calculate a rate- (G21) or (K21) respectively. I guess since there is a formula there it cannot ignore the fact that it is blank. I was hoping there is a way around that.

Answer (score 1):

Look at where you paste to, you paste to K39 then K40 then to K39 again and K40 again overwriting the previous pastes so it always looks like it isn't doing that first copy because the second one has gone ove the top.

Comment: Thank you. This form I created is a rate calculator and the user should only be enter data into cells either cells G16:G18 OR cells K16:K18 based on rate type (daily or package charge) not both.

Comment: Then in cells G21 and K21 a formula calculates the rate to client based on the data entry in the ranges mentioned in my first comment. The first range of cells copies over with no issue. It only seems to be the cells with formulas I have the issue with.

Comment: It seems to ignore the blank cells when there is no formula entered. But for the cells that do have a formula the overwriting issue mentioned above happens and the data is copied as "" even if there is information in the previous cells.  @Dan Donoghue

Comment: The code runs sequentially, look at the 3rd and 4th copy and paste then look at the 5th and 6th, the 5th and 6th overwrite anything that happened from the 3rd and 4th. They paste to the same cells.

Comment: Yes sir, thank you! I used an if statement and got it working precisely how I need it too. I really appreciate you taking a look at it.